# get the price for an item according to salesdate based on price history table in DB2

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

Im working with a db2 server that has a database called mobility. inside the database there is a table named pricehistory, sales, salesdetail. Pricehistory contains productcode,effectivitydate,and unitprice.
Sales table contains transaction number, and salesdate. And table salesdetail contains transno,quantity and productcode.

Im trying to obtain a result which would show me the correct unitprice for the product code in salesdetail table based on the salesdate in sales table and the effectivity date in table pricehistory.

I data below is shown for better overview of the problem

```
PriceHistoryTable
Effdate    productcode     unitprice 
05/15/2010  NB0001           300.00
05/15/2010  PF0005           119.00 
08/16/2010  PF0005           108.18
```

Table Sales

[image: Table Sales]

Table Salesdetail

[image: Table Salesdetail]

im trying to achieve having a result set that looks like this

```
**Transno**   **Productcode  **salesdate**    unitprice** 
TR000006         NB0001       2010-07-07        300.00
TR000006         PF0005       2010-07-07        119.00
```

Comment: please tag appropriately. If you are using DB2, please remove `mysql` and `sql-server` tag

Comment: ...I'm a little worried here.  If you have a transaction log table, you should be storing off what you sold the product for (at least in cases like coupons, discounts granted by salesmen, etc).  Do we not need to worry about something like that?  Also, `quantity` appears to be non-integral, which seems... dangerous (and before anybody says "weight!", item count and weight of product are two very different attributes, and should be treated as such).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse..."item count" is not the same as "quantity sold"  unless the selling unit is EACH.  If the selling unit is FEET or LBS, then a decimal value for quantity sold makes sense.  Most third party systems I've seen allow for a decimal quantity as there's no way to know how a customer will use it.